# How to increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size?

Tags: node.js

On a GoDaddy MySQL database, I'm getting this error:

```
 error: code: "ER_TOO_BIG_ROWSIZE"errno: 1118index: 0sql: "UPDATE `cloudmeetin` 
 SET `userId` = 'abhi', 
`fullName"sqlMessage: 
"The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of 
redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.
```

How do increase the size?

Comment: Please help me regarding this error.

Comment: Simplified title, clarified question.

Answer (score 1):

---

[image]

---

**STEP 1 => Try to increase "innodb_log_file_size" from my.ini file.**
[image]

---

**STEP 2 => Increase size-->**

[image]

---

**STEP 3 => Then re-start your XAMPP/WAMP/LAMP/MAMP.**

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase your "innodb_log_file_size" by default this error is raised when you try to create a blob/text column greater than 10% of this value.

You can read more about [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)